# What is the patern to search for any string which respect this format "CEC0000-0000"?

Tags: php, regex

The zeros can be incremented but it must be of four digits, so it could be CEC0152-2005
Of course with a "-" between them.
I used www.txt2re.com to generate this patern but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe,

```
^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$
```

or,

```
^CEC[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$
```

might work fine.

#### Test

```
$re = '/^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$/m';
$str = 'CEC0152-2005
CEC0152-2019
CEC0152-1999
CEC0152-19991';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "CEC0152-2005"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "CEC0152-2019"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "CEC0152-1999"
  }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gIBFix/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/gIBFix/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If after the dash we'd have a four-digit year,

```
^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}-[12][0-9]{3}$
^CEC[0-9]{4}-[12][0-9]{3}$
```

might also work fine, I guess.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/jqtfLO/1/)

Comment: thanks @Emma, I update it to ^CEC[0-9]{4}-[12][0-9]{3}$ because it should contains CEC in the start (that's my faut because i didn't clarify it in my question), thank you again Emma